# What does the + sign mean in vim patterns when used to quote a pattern?

Tags: vim

The vim help example gives this line for a syntax statement:

```
:syntax region String   start=+"+  skip=+\\"+  end=+"+
```

Is the `+` sign here an alternative to quoting? I couldn't find a reference to this in the help pages on patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An introduction to patterns, see `:h pattern.txt`. As in the example of chapter 10 (`:h :match`), `:match MyGroup /TODO/`, instead of `//` any character can be used to mark the start and end of the *pattern*.

Like your question (`:h syntax.txt`), this is explained in Chapter 8 (`:h :syn-pattern`) :

> In the syntax commands, a pattern must be surrounded by two identical characters. This is like it works for the ":s" command.  The most common to use is the double quote. But if the pattern contains a double quote, you can use another character that is not used in the pattern. Examples: `:syntax region String start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+`

Just like the `:s` command, see `:h :s` and `:h pattern-delimiter`, the benefit and convenience is the handling of escape characters. Using the `:s` command as an example is more convenient for you to verify quickly.

If you want to replace `a` with `b`, you can use `:s/a/b/` or `:s+a+b+`. But if you want to replace `/` with `//`, using delimiter `/` require `:s/\//\/\//`, we can change the delimiter `/` to `+` (`:s+\/+\/\/+`). Actually, here we no longer need to escape `/`, so in the end there is only a concise `:s+/+//+`.

Back to your question, if the pattern contains a lot of double quotes, we can use another character that is not used in the pattern as delimiter (e.g. `+`), otherwise each double quote in the pattern needs to be escaped.

Comment: I can't beleive it was right there and my eyes went passed it. Thanks for this great response.

Answer (score 2):

That sample command in your question isn't provided without context. It is provided as an illustration for **the paragraph right above it**:

> In the syntax commands, a pattern must be surrounded by two identical
> characters.  This is like it works for the ":s" command.  The most common to
> use is the double quote.  But if the pattern contains a double quote, you can
> use another character that is not used in the pattern.